# Issue:- Incompability in data issue Source document: eav_attribute_group. Field: attribute_group_name. Error:

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

**During Magento1.9.3.4 to Magento2.1.8 Migration Getting following issues :-**

Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute_group. Field: attribute_group_name. Error: The product attribute set "Default" does not contain all required attribute group names "General, Prices, Design, Images"

I've attached screenshot.

[image]

**Note:-** Also implement R&D solutions but issue still not resolved.

Comment: Any update please, it's very urgent issue so guys please help me to get rid off.

Answer (score 0):

After hard work, I configured DB with fresh Magento files then checked attribute group & find that "General" group was renamed as "Basic Info" after changing this to "General" **my issue has been resolved**.

Thanks!!!